# Can I Merge two OSX accounts

Tags: macos, user-account

I have two accounts on my MacBook (OSX 12.6.5).  I can access each account fine but I would like all the files to be in just one account.

Can I merge the two accounts?

Answer (score 1):

There's no tool to merge accounts, but you could use Finder or a tool like `rsync` to copy files and then make a list of duplicates and decide how to handle them.

Most people find it easier to just pick the account with the settings they like and [move all the documents to the cloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985) (or to a folder in /Users/Shared) that both accounts can read / write and get things unified.

How did you come to have two user accounts? (Perhaps that will yield a different specific answer.)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Contents of an old iMac were copied to a separate account on my new MacBook.  The difficulty is that the two accounts seems to have some files in common - new items on the desktop of one account are appearing on the desktop of the other...?

Comment: Aah - so you may have disk directory corruption too. Make a Time Machine backup now and then see about repairing the disk in recovery mode @Dan. Then you should have better foundation to try a merge and cleanup or know you need to erase and install both accounts for, the current backup and hope nothing important was corrupted or lost.

Comment: Dan - was this done as a clean install with default new account added - *then* a separate later migration?

Comment: @Tetsujin - My Macbook had a single account on it.  The contents of an old iMac were put into a new account at a later date (does that answer your question?)

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't done as a migrate, then as bmike says - manual copy is the way to go.